# Importing non-Android Java Library into Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

I would like to import a non-Android Java library to an Android project.

Based on my research, there seem to be two main options:

1. Add the source code of the Java library as a separate module. However, the source code cannot simply be imported (e.g. added as a subrepo) since the Android package names would need to be added to each file.
2. Add a JAR file of the Java library. I have been following the instructions available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library), and the project builds successfully, though I am still unable to import classes from the library. I suspect this may be because the project is a standalone Java library rather than an Android library.

Any advice on how to add the library (either as a JAR or as a copy of the existing library) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the ***jar*** file for the library under *app/libs* and make sure your *app/build.gradle* file has the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

After you've included the *jar* file, click on the *"Sync Project with Gradle Files"* button. After the sync is complete you should be able to use the classes in the library.